# Citing a range of papers using numeric keys as in \cite{a, b, c} -> [1-3]

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, natbib, citing, cite-package

How can I cite a range of papers, the output is a **range of numbers**, instead of a list of numbers? In other words, when I type

```
... some dummy text here is due to me \cite{me1, me2, me3, me4} ...
```

I want the output to be

> ... some dummy text here is due to me [3-6] ...

instead of

> ... some dummy text here is due to me [3.4.5.6] ...

(I use LaTeX, and am currently using the `amsart` class and whatever it includes. But I am open to other suggestions.)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The [`cite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite), [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib), and [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) packages, at least, will all do this.

---

A minimal example which demonstrates the behaviour is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello \cite{article-full,book-full,mastersthesis-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

If you have basic bibliography needs, adding `\usepackage{cite}` will produce the desired behaviour.

If you have more complex bibliography needs, nowadays I recommend `biblatex` as a first choice, although `natbib` has a long and distinguished history in this space and is possibly a better option if you want a more ‘stable’ solution.

For `biblatex`, you would now write this example as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{xampl}
\begin{document}
hello \cite{article-full,book-full,mastersthesis-full}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Noting that you need to process the bibliography using `biber` instead of `bibtex`. (You can use `bibtex` by adding `backend=bibtex` to the package options, but I'm not sure if that is currently recommended for new documents.)

If you are using `natbib`, a minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
hello \citep{article-full,booklet-full,mastersthesis-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, the `cite` package. That gives a minimal work solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: (I also realized that the `amsrefs` package can do it, but I didn't feel like retyping 92 citation entries.)

Comment: warning -- `biblatex` hasn't been tested with `amsart`, and i can't predict whether it will work; i'm inclined to think it may not be totally smooth sailing.

Comment: Hi will, is there any chance of expanding the answer? This seems to be high up on google, but it is a bit unspecific. Just as the question :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B — thanks for noticing; what do you think of the new text?

Comment: Apparently `natbib`   does not like the `{}`  directly in front of years. Apart from that, good update. It will be more helpful in the future. By the way, i started to rewrite parts of the wikibook -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Comment: @Johannes_B Hmmmf. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: natbib produces a good number of error messages like `Missing } inserted.` and `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`, same for biber, both exporting bibtex and biblatex with Zotero. Am I doing something _obviously_ wrong?

Answer (score 52):

if you add

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

to your preamble, you should get the expected result.

Comment: one question! 
In the case of the 'cite' package, it ok to use:
'\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{cite}'

Comment: If I test it, I see that `\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` seems to be the same as `\usepackage{cite}` if using the plain bibliography style. The options of the cite package can be found in its documentation (numbers isn't one of them...).

Answer (score 36):

Using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html), sorting and compressing numeric keys is achieved with

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Can confirm that it works for LyX Version 2.3.6.1, by using as configs:
Tools -> Preferences -> Output -> LaTeX -> processor=biber
and in
Document -> Settings -> Bibliography 
I've put citation style = numeric-comp
and bibliography style = ieee, but this latter one won't matter, I'm just being thorough about something that behaves as expected for my use case, which was appearence order and the citing range [as wanted by OP]