# How to display citations in text grouped as [1-3] in stead of [1,2,3]

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing a range of papers (using numeric keys)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys)

In Latex I am using BibTex for the bibliography and use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to manage my references.

When I use multiple references i.e. `\cite{article1,article2,article3}` I would love to see this appear in the text as:

```
blah blah [1-3] blah blah
```

instead I get:

```
blah blah [1, 2, 3] blah blah
```

I use the format of `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` because it numbers the references in the order they appear and would like to keep this feature but I could be flexible on which style I use.

Comment: Dupe of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys I think

Answer (score 45):

`\usepackage{cite}` should do the trick

Comment: Much simpler solution than: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys

Comment: `pdflatex` reads that `cite` package is incompatible.