# Cite multiple references with Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

So I use bibtex and I have set my `\bibliographystyle` to be unsrt. I want Latex to render something like this:

**ref [1]-[5] support this claim.**

but if i write:

```
\cite{x1} - \cite{x5} blah blah
```

citation items 2, 3 and 4 are not gonna be listed in the bibliography list in the end, whereas I want them to be present. How can I do it?

Comment: You can load `cite` package and say `ref~\cite{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}` to get `ref [1-5]`. FYI, you can include citations in bibliography list by using `\nocite{x2,x3,x4}`

Comment: @lockstep oops. didn't see that although this is in a slightly different setting.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should include all the references in the `\cite` command, without a blankspace, for them to appear in the *Bibliography* chapter:

```
\cite{citation01,citation02,citation03,citation04,citation05}
```

Don't forget to include:

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

in the preamble. The output should be something like:

> Refs [1-5] support this claim.

[Similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15113/how-to-display-citations-in-text-grouped-as-1-3-in-stead-of-1-2-3)

Comment: note that if you want to include page numbers, you can use `\cites[1--3]{citation01}[7--9]{citation02}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18911/

Comment: For those that need it: you can't have whitespace in the comma-separated list.

Comment: As far as I can tell @GlabbichRulz' comment refers to `biblatex` not `bibtex`.