# How to make one reference to multiple citations

Tags: bibtex

I'd like to do following thing. In my text I want to refer to citations with

```
\cite{ref1}
```

and in the reference section under this reference, e.g. [1] there should be sth. as follows:

[1] (a) author1, author2, ..., journal1, vol1, pp1 year1, (b) author3, author4, ..., journal2, vol2, pp2, year2 (c) and so on

It is not the question about the style of the reference, but how to make many references (a), (b), (c) under one citation [1]?

Comment: This does not provide answer to your exact question, but consider using package `cite', and using it like described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127156/cite-multiple-references-with-bibtex/

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

biblatex/biber supports fixed sets (@set in the bib) and dynamic sets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[subentry]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibentryset{multi}{shore,angenendt,westfahl:space}

\begin{document}
\cite{set}
\cite{multi} \cite{shore}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]