# Hyphenate a series of consecutively numbered references

Tags: bibtex, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing a range of papers (using numeric keys)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys)

I am using the package `bibentry` and the `\cite` command to include numerical references to a bibliography. If one cites multiple consecutive references, the series is displayed as a comma separated list (e.g., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]). Is it possible to have such a list displayed using only the first and last references in the series, separated by a hyphen or en-dash (e.g., [1--8])? Preferably, this method would also work with lists that comprise consecutive and non-consecutive elements (e.g, [1, 3, 4, 5] would become [1, 3--5]).

Here is an MWE demonstrating inability to hyphenate a series of references with `bibentry`:
[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{bibentry}
    \begin{document}
    Accumulating evidence indicates that the Earth is round~\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}.
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{refs}
    \end{document}
```

The `bibentry` source files are included in the [natbib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) package, but it is not mentioned in the pdf documentation files.

Comment: The related discussion indicates that this is possible with `cite`, `biblatex`, and `natbib` packages. By referring me to that discussion, do you imply that this is not possible with the `bibentry` package?

Comment: [`bibentry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibentry) is "distributed as part of the [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) bundle" and should therefore work. If not, [edit your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/39683/edit) and update it to show the difference(s) and `flag` the post for moderator attention to request it be re-opened.

Comment: @user001 Have you actually tried using `natbib` or `cite` to solve the problem? As `bibentry` is part of `natbib`, I suspect the latter will work fine.

Comment: user001: Could you please provide more information as requested by @JosephWright, so we can decide about your re-opening request. Thanks.