# Citing references in order

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing a range of papers (using numeric keys)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys)

I notice that in some papers, people cite references as `[1-5]`, or as `[1,2,3]`. The idea is that their references are numbered in increasing order. How do they do this? My references come out all over the place in `\bibliographystyle{plain}` as, for example, `[2,3,1,4,5,7,9]`.

Comment: not quite. i want the package the put the refs in numerical order when they're not. that's the key point, not grouping them.

Comment: Load the `cite` package: `\usepackage{cite}` and reprocess the document (`pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex`) to rebuild the bibliography and the citationss.

Comment: Also, by default when you load `cite` the references come out `[1-5]`. If you want `[1,2,3,4,5]`, you need to use the option `nocompress`. Also, if you want more space than the default amount between the numbers in a citation, you can use the option `space`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Plain` orders references by name, if you look at your bibliography you'll see that it is alphabetical. To get your references in order of appearance use the style `unsrt`.

Comment: Actually, that's precisely what I needed. In combination with the cite package as mentioned by Gonzalo above, it works perfectly! Thank you folks!

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation points to +1 everyone here.

Comment: @ethiopianqubit I'll do it for you :)