# On using \cite or something else to group successive references together

Tags: citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing a range of papers (using numeric keys)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys)

Quick question. Let's say I have five references to cite which are A to E. Currently, I'm using `\cite{A,B,C,D,E}` which produces

> [1,2,3,8,11]

How do I modify it so that it produces the output of

> [1-3,8,11]

or at least it groups the consecutive references together so as not to have a very long output format? I hope this is possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} as suggested in the link and continue to use \cite{A,B,C,D,E} in the body. However, it did not do the job. I wonder if I missed out something.

Comment: Without a minimal working example that shows the problem, it's hard to say.

Comment: Without loading `natbib` you can try with `\usepackage{cite}`

Comment: This is what I had in my latex file --> "....balance data rate and complexity \cite{Lee,Li,Manchon}" and it comes out "....balance data rate and complexity [27, 28, 29]" although I declared the natbib package with the preambles as above. @egreg, must I include any preambles for the cite package? Thanks for you help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Oh I've tried using @egreg's suggestion and declared cite package without any preambles. It worked beautifully! Thanks for all your help! Now, I have to figure out how to format it so that it comes out as [27]-[29] instead of [27-29].

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have found the complete solution to my question. I will share it here just in case it is useful to others as most sites do not provide the answer explicitly. Special thanks to **@lockstep** and **@egreg** for providing helpful comments.

I will use the [**cite package**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/supported/cite) as the solution. Just include the following statements when you declare your latex packages.

> \usepackage{cite} \def\citepunct{], [} \def\citedash{]--[}

To utilize it, simply use \cite{} for your references. Taking the alphabets to mean numerical progression, we have the following examples:

> \cite{RefA, RefB, RefC, RefD} --> [1]-[4]

while,

> \cite{RefA, RefC, RefD, RefE, RefG} --> [1],[3]-[5],[7]

Hope this helps.