# How can I write a group of reference briefly? ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] change to [1-5] but show the all refer on reference)

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citing a range of papers (using numeric keys)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys)

When we are writing a article we should `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` change to `[1-5]` but show the all refer on reference. How can I do this? In addition, I use a `MyReferences.bib` file and below code

‎

```
\pagestyle{empty}‎
{
‎\onehalfspacing‎
‎\bibliographystyle{unsrt-fa}
‎\bibliography{MyReferences}‎
}
```

It is very important that write all refer on reference (at the end of article).

Comment: You can use the `cite` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [cite](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package but you are using a style `usrt-fa` for XePersian that produce a error (*Environment LTRbibitems undefined*) when applied to  [this minimal working example](http://texblog.org/2007/05/28/mulitple-reference-citation/).

But it works perfectly  with the original  `\bibliographystyle{plain}` or  even with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.

Probably adding your own MWE (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ) to the question that work in a persian document will help to find a better solution.