# How to cite [1-2] using \usepackage{cite}?

Tags: citing, cite-package, multiple-citations, abntex2

When I make a citation like \cite{a,b} the result is [a,b]. However, how can I make the following command \cite{a,b} produce the citation [1-2]?

This same question was answered for the natbib package in: [Cite like [1-2] instead of [1, 2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86987/289248)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\renewcommand\citepunct{-}` from the `cite` package. It replaces all commas by `-`. But this would be weird if you have more than 2 citations in your `\cite` command (if you cite reference 1 and reference 3, you obtain [1-3] which reads: reference 1 to reference 3, with reference 2 included).

In the below code, the `\usepackage{filecontents}` can be omitted in recent LaTeX versions (eg 2022 version).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliotest.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
  
  @book{Lam86,
    title = {LaTeX: a document preparation system},
    author = {Lamport, Leslie},
    year = {1986},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citepunct{-}

\begin{document}

\cite{Knu86,Lam86}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliotest}
\end{document}
```

[image]