# Cite a range of references

Tags: bibliographies, plain-tex

I have a very long list of citations in my `TeX` file. Rather than each bibliographic key appearing in the list, I would like a range of values, e.g. given

```
\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4}
```

I get

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

but would prefer

```
[1-4].
```

I am using `TeX` + `Eplain` + `BibTeX`. Any suggestions? I have tried using a few LaTeX packages (`cite`,`mcite`, and `natbib`), but (unsurprisingly) they all fail to load.

Comment: Have you already checked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys?

Comment: Have you tried loading the `cite` package using an `\input` statement, i.e., as `\input cite.sty %`?

Comment: @Nico That post doesn't really work here as I am using plain TeX as opposed to LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico That doesn't work as `cite.sty` is a LaTeX package and so it has macros that are not defined in `TeX`.

Answer (score 2):

OPmac is plainTeX specific. You can use it. See [this page](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html).

```
\input opmac-bib

\sortcitations  % the cites are sorted in each \cite[a,b,c,d]
\shortcitations % the intervals [a--d] instead [a,b,c,d] are printed

Here is \cite[white,texbook,nierhaus,lech]
and \cite[demay,rowling].

\nonum\sec References

\rightskip=0em plus 5em
\usebib/s (iso690) op-example % op-example.bib plus iso690 bib style is used

\bye
```

The `op-example.bib`, `opmac-bib.tex`, `opmac.tex` and `opmac-bib-iso690.tex` files were used from [this page](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html) (see the end of the page). You can try to process this example by `pdftex document` twice. **No bibTeX is needed**. All processing is done at TeX level. The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with (pdf) latex, you can use `biblatex` with its `numeric-comp` or `numeric-icomp` citation styles ("comp" is for "compact"; choice to be given as an option in the preamble) together with the `\cites` and its siblings commands.

See the details in §3.3.1 and 3.7.3 of the documentation.

Comment: Note that OP uses plain TeX with eplain, not LaTeX.

Comment: That's precisely why I wrote: _if_ you compile with (pdf)latex, thereby meaning "perhaps you should consider using (pdf)latex". As far as I understand it, neither natbib nor (m)cite are plaintex sets of macros.

Comment: @Bernard You are right at `natbib` and `mcite` are LaTeX specific. They won't work for me here.