# What is the substitute for \usepackage{cite} in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations, multiple-citations

I want my references to appear as [5-8] instead of citing multiple references [5, 6, 7, 8] in beamer presentation mode. I tried \usepackage{cite}, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal experience, these kinds of citations are quite useless in an actual conference/thesis presentation. However, you might be writing some lecture presentation where these could be more useful. In any case, here is a reminder on the recommandations regarding citations inside of a `beamer` presentation (see `beamer` user guide §5.1.2 p 34).

> **Bibliographies**. You may also wish to present a bibliography at the end of your talk, so that people can see
> what kind of “further reading” is possible. When adding a bibliography to a presentation, keep the following in
> mind:
>
> - It is a bad idea to present a long bibliography in a presentation. Present only very few references. (Naturally,
>   this applies only to the talk itself, not to a possible handout.)
> - If you present more references than fit on a single slide you can be almost sure that none of them will be
>   remembered.
> - Present references only if they are intended as “further reading.” Do not present a list of all things you
>   used like in a paper.
> - You should not present a long list of all your other great papers except if you are giving an application
>   talk.
>   34
> - Using the \cite commands can be confusing since the audience has little chance of remembering the
>   citations. If you cite the references, always cite them with full author name and year like “[Tantau, 2003]”
>   instead of something like “[2,4]” or “[Tan01,NT02]”.
> - If you want to be modest, you can abbreviate your name when citing yourself as in “[Nickelsen and T.,
>   2003]” or “[Nickelsen and T, 2003]”. However, this can be confusing for the audience since it is often not
>   immediately clear who exactly “T.” might be. We recommend using the full name.

Regardless of these recommandations, your question is very close to [Citing a range of papers using numeric keys as in \cite{a, b, c} -> [1-3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3871/141947).
Will Robertson's nice answer [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3874/141947) provides three options to obtain the desired result.

As you pointed out, `\usepackage{cite}` does not suffice here.
However the other two options (with either `biblatex` or `natbib`) work fine with `beamer`.
I recall them here, but these are pretty much copy pasted from Will Robertson's answer.

**With biblatex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{xampl}
\begin{document}
hello \cite{article-full,book-full,mastersthesis-full}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**With natbib**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
hello \citep{article-full,booklet-full,mastersthesis-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted, any specific reason why ? As stated, this is not an answer yet