# Separated multiple references in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex. If I cite

> \cite{author1,author2}

I obtain

> [1], [2].

How could I cite such that references now live under the same bracket,

> [1,2]?

Comment: Use `style=numeric-comp,` instead of `style=numeric,`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3871/35864.

Comment: ... Though now I think about this again, the default output for `style=numeric,` should be "[1,2]" already. If you get "[1], [2]" either you are not using `style=numeric,` or something is wrong. `numeric-comp` should only become relevant once you cite a larger range ("[1,2,3]" vs "[1-3]"). Please show us a small example document that reproduces the output you are currently getting with as little code as possible.

Comment: It worked with `\usepackage[style=ieee,style=numeric]{biblatex}`! However, the cites now appear not by order of appearance, but `[1,124]`, for example.

Comment: With `\usepackage[style=ieee,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` it was solved! Thank you.

Comment: `\usepackage[style=ieee,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` is equivalent to `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` because multiple `style`s overwrite each other.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, you were using `style=ieee,` which displays all citations in separate brackets.

If you don't particularly care about IEEE style in the bibliography, you can just go for

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

to get the usual behaviour that places all numbers in the same pair of brackets.

If you want to compress ranges as well, use `numeric-comp` instead of numeric. See [Citing a range of papers using numeric keys as in \cite{a, b, c} -> [1-3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3871/35864).

If you want to retain the IEEE bibliography style, you can select `numeric` only as citation style

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
```